# File size increase by 1KB after saving it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am saving an image file in a SQL Server column (datatype `varbinary(max)`). Code to save file in database:

```
Stream fs = imgUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
conn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbEHUsers set photo=@binaryValue where UserID="+Session["UserID"].ToString(), conn))
{                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = bytes;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

Get image data from SQL Server:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo from tbEHUsers where UserID=" + Session["UserID"], con);
SqlDataReader rdr = CMD.ExecuteReader();
byte[] imgArray = null;

while (rdr.Read())
{
        imgArray = (byte[])rdr["Photo"];
}

File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\Test12345.jpg", imgArray);
```

Original size of file which I uploaded was 858KB however after retrieving from database and saving it again using `File.WriteAllBytes` method it increases to 859KB. Now when I try to open this file I get 'corrupted file error'. The byte array size was same both the time while saving and retrieving.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Compare your files using a hex editor. Where is the extra data being inserted? At the start? At the end? And importantly, what is being inserted?

Comment: You should use a **parameter** for the `UserID` in your queries!

Answer (score 0):

When using FileUpload.PostedFile you need to reset the InputStream to start from the beginning again. So add the following line on top of your code:

```
imgUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```